# How to Trigger/Initialise Excel VB User Forms Without Showing the Workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have created an excel vba tool that utilises userforms to create a shopping experience for the user. Once the user opens the tool he will be able to pick orders from the user form. The code then processes the orders and returns with a calculated estimated cost.

The Problem is I don't want to let the workbook(and sheets in it) visible to the user. I need to hide my active workbook without any pop ups.

I recently crossed with the below solution however, I found out that upon initial launch by the user, he encountered "**Security Warning** Macros have been disabled. Enable Content (button)" which renders the initial solution worthless. Any advice is appreciated. TIA.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any way for VBA to suppress that security warning.  Perhaps if you had code running in Outlook then you might be able to quietly handle the warning in Excel but I'm fairly sceptical and it would surely depend on specific user settings that are "generally" out of your control.

Comment: VBA runs hosted in a host application, in this case Excel. If you don't need a host, consider writing a stand-alone application in VB.NET or C# - that won't need a host, so there won't be a need to pretend there's no host.

Answer (score 0):

forgot to mention the obvious

XLAM

save your book as an xlam.  put it in the addin folder (or explicitly point to it) and select it through Excel's interface.

addins are not visible by default

you still have to manage the security warning, frankly this is a user concern that you'll likely be forced to address and it's an issue that will never go away.

i will not say this is "good" advice and you may scof or reject the idea on principle, but if you don't have a legit way of signing your projects, consider the possibility of installing a personal cert on the users computer and signing the project locally or walking users through the process remotely

Comment: I was planning to store the tool I created in a Shared Drive for everyone within the network to use. I have never signed a project maybe I should look into it.

Answer (score -1):

You can permanently enable macros for a certain workbook in the Trust Center of the excel workbook. So whenever the user opens the workbook, he/she will not need press the button each time to activate anything macro related.

[image]

In your case you want to select: `Enable all macros (not recommended; potentially dangerous code can run)`

Comment: Is there a way to specify the workbook I can trust to run macros? That way any user will feel safer instead of enabling all macros by default.

Comment: You can digitally sign the workbook. Please refer to this post: https://superuser.com/questions/1126733/enable-macros-for-specific-excel-file

Comment: Wonderfull. I will check on it.